# Does anyone know how to use GRAlertView file to customise the alertView?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have the GRAlertView files with me. I imported them to my project. still i am not getting the customised view in my output view. How is that so? I am getting a normal alert view.

Comment: I am sure this will help you https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView.

Comment: That link is the same one i reffered to.. But in that it is saying to jus import those .m and .h files in my project. I tried that way but the output has no effect.

Comment: After importing those files.. this is the code i used in my project

Comment: Refer the examples given in README.md file.

Comment: I reffered to it.. its jus saying to import the files…which i have done but still there is no effect. Please help me out since i am a beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link [GRAlertView](https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView).

Try this after importing the files.

Alert with icon:

```
GRAlertView *alert = [[GRAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:@"Be careful!"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.style = GRAlertStyleAlert;            // set UIAlertView style
        alert.animation = GRAlertAnimationLines;    // set animation type
        [alert setImage:@"alert.png"];              // add icon image
        [alert show];
```

Custom Alert with icon:

```
GRAlertView *alert = [[GRAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Alert"
                                           message:@"Merry Christmas!"
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];

        [alert setTopColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]
               middleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]
               bottomColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]
                 lineColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];

        [alert setFontName:@"Cochin-BoldItalic"
                 fontColor:[UIColor greenColor]
           fontShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];

        [alert setImage:@"santa.png"];
        [alert show];
```

**Note :** Copied the example from [GRAlertView](https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView) , as OP is not understanding the comments

Comment: Yes... i understood the comments also i tried the above code... still the output is the same.. no change. U can try it out and check.

Comment: I have used the second code for custom alert. Created a button in viewDidLoad and in the select of the button, i put this above code. Somehow the customisation part of it is not getting used,dont know how.